# How to bring back the horizontal line, Advance Search and Search Tips back in GSA using the frontend stylesheet

Tags: frontend, stylesheet, google-search-appliance

This is my GSA(1)
[image]

This is the other GSA(2) which I want to mimic:

[image]

You will see that there is a line break between **“Search: public content, public and secure content”** and **“Powered by Google Search Appliance”**. Also my GSA doesn't have Adavanced Search and Search Tips Option which is near **"Google Search"** box. I know there is a setting in the frontend stylesheet which can change that, but I am not able to find exactly where I have to do that.
This is the part of the frontend style sheet for Advanced Search and Search Tips:

```
<xsl:variable name="choose_result_page_header">both</xsl:variable>
<!--  *** customize provided result page header ***  -->
<xsl:variable name="show_swr_link">1</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="swr_search_anchor_text">Search Within Results</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="show_result_page_adv_link">1</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="adv_search_anchor_text">Advanced Search</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="show_result_page_help_link">1</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="search_help_anchor_text">Search Tips</xsl:variable>
```

But I coudn't find anything for the line break between “Search: public content, public and secure content” and “Powered by Google Search Appliance”.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a text comparison tool like Beyond Compare to compare your XSLT to the Google "default" one.  It will point out the differences and so you can skim through the differences until you find the correct place where you've removed the items you want back.

Answer (score 0):

There is some fairly hairy XSLT in the presentation layer.  Make a default view with no changes at all, and compare with your edited version.  I've seen external links to scripts and XSLT that disappeared when I changed anything on a line, so a good strategy is to make a default view and then make changes very slowly, testing as you go.